# Python regex a binary file text file - how to use a range of numbers and word boundry?

Tags: python, regex, binaryfiles, python-3.6

I have a text file that requires me to read it in binary and write out in binary.  No problem.  I need to mask out Social Security Numbers with Xs, pretty easy normally:

`text = re.sub("\\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\{4}\\b","XXX-XX-XXXX", text)`

This is a sample of the text I'm parsing:

`more stuff here
CHILDREN�S 001-02-0003 get rid of that
stuff goes here
not001-02-0003
but ssn:001-02-0003`

and I need to turn it into this:

`more stuff here
CHILDREN�S XXX-XX-XXXX get rid of that
stuff goes here
not001-02-0003
but ssn:XXX-XX-XXXX`

Super! So now I'm trying to write that same regex 'in binary'.  Here is what I've got and it's 'works' but gosh it doesn't feel right at all:

`line = re.sub(b"\\B(\x000|\x001|\x002|\x003|\x004|\x005|\x006|\x007|\x008|\x009)(\x000|\x001|\x002|\x003|\x004|\x005|\x006|\x007|\x008|\x009)(\x000|\x001|\x002|\x003|\x004|\x005|\x006|\x007|\x008|\x009)\x00-(\x000|\x001|\x002|\x003|\x004|\x005|\x006|\x007|\x008|\x009)(\x000|\x001|\x002|\x003|\x004|\x005|\x006|\x007|\x008|\x009)\x00-(\x000|\x001|\x002|\x003|\x004|\x005|\x006|\x007|\x008|\x009)(\x000|\x001|\x002|\x003|\x004|\x005|\x006|\x007|\x008|\x009)(\x000|\x001|\x002|\x003|\x004|\x005|\x006|\x007|\x008|\x009)(\x000|\x001|\x002|\x003|\x004|\x005|\x006|\x007|\x008|\x009)\\B", b"\x00X\x00X\x00X\x00-\x00X\x00X\x00-\x00X\x00X\x00X\x00X", line)`

Notes:

- that junk in CHILDRENS, gotta keep it like that
- need to word boundary, thus the 4th line doesn't get masked out

Shouldn't my regex be a range of numbers instead?  I just don't know how to do that in binary.  And my word boundaries only work *backwards* as \B instead of \b, uh.. what is up with that?

**UPDATE**: I've also tried this:

`line = re.sub(b"[\x30-\x39]", b"\x58", line)`

and that does it for EVERY number, but if I try to even do something simple like:

`line = re.sub(b"[\x30-\x39][\x30-\x39]", b"\x58\x58", line)`

it doesn't match anything anymore, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b')

with open("test.txt", "rb") as fr, open("test2.txt", "wb+") as fp:
    repl = rx.sub('XXX-XX-XXXX', fr.read())
    fp.write(repl)
```

This keeps every junk characters as they are and writes them to `test2.txt`.
Note that, when you don't want every backslash escaped, you could use `r'string here'` in `Python`.

Comment: There is a pile of 'broken' type characters so I need to process it as binary.  Some are UTF-8 but people have stuck windings and what not in and due to business requirements (kill me) I need to keep the busted characters and simply strip out the SSNs.  If I go for UTF-8 encoding I start to get all kinds of encoding errors.

Comment: specifically with the trash file I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: @sniperd: Updated, does this work for you? I get the same junk chars back in `test2.txt` here.

Comment: I get this message: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object  ug.  I'm going to give up soon and just uh.. cry.  I think in the end I'm going to need to KNOW the encoding of what is coming in.  I do very much appreciate the effort.